Number of solutions in an ordering game
A group of $n$ people play a game where they each select two others, one is assigned as their 'Attacker' and the other their 'Defender'. The goal is for the entire group to position themselves in a line such that their defender is between them and their attacker. Sometimes this is possible, and sometimes not. (See example for a valid and invalid configuration) The question is, for a group selecting randomly, what are the odds they can form a valid ordering?
The total number of possible attacker/defender assignments was straightforward to find, where each person chooses two others, and each selection has two A/D configurations.
$(2{ n-1 \choose 2})^n = ((n-1)(n-2))^n$
But of these, how can the number of assignments with a solution be found? If we consider a given assignment R, I was thinking that each assignment could be thought of as an ordering, so for a set of people G, with $x_i, x_{A_i}, x_{D_i} \in G$,  either $(x_i < x_{D_i} < x_{A_i})$ or $(x_{A_i} < x_{D_i} < x_i) \in R$.
Then only the relations that form a partial order would have a valid solution. But I'm not entirely sure how to determine how many assignments are partially ordered.
Additionally, given a valid assignment, how many totally ordered solutions are there? This, from what I read, is a difficult problem generally, so it may not have an easy answer.

You can find the total number of total orderings by lining people up first and then picking attackers and defenders.  For example, with 4 people, there are 24 ways to line them up, then $3×1×1×3$ ways to assign attackers and defenders.  Of course it doesn't help you when attackers and defenders are already assigned.
